# jQuery Toggle classes not toggeling

Tags: jquery

When a user click an toggle button I would to change all classes with the name `textfield` to `editable_textfield`

I am using this toggle button / checkbox

```
<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-on="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>" data-off="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>" data-onstyle="danger">
```

When a user click the button there is no change of class, I have here 1 example of this class

```
<span class="textfield" data-type="text" data-name="naam" data-
pk="'.$row_table_1['id'].'" data-url="post.php">'.$row_table_1['naam'].'</span>
```

jQuery is loaded on this page.

```
$(function() {
    $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
        $(element).toggleClass("textfield editable_textfield");
    })
})
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your related jQuery snippet?

Comment: You don't appear to have written any code to change the class of the target span.

Comment: Sorry, mistake with copy / paste, added the missing code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the checkbox *toggle* the span's state, then you would have to execute the `toggleClass` function on multiple elements, as shown below. I replaced your checkbox value with plain text for the demo and added several span elements including styling to their classes `textfield` and `editable_textfield` to demonstrate behavior.

```js
$('#toggle-event').change(function() {
  $('.textfield, .editable_textfield').toggleClass('textfield editable_textfield');
});
```

```css
span.textfield {
  background: red;
}

span.editable_textfield {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-on="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>" data-off="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>" data-onstyle="danger">

<span class="textfield" data-type="text" data-name="naam" data-
pk="'.$row_table_1['id'].'" data-url="post.php">Hello World</span>

<span class="textfield" data-type="text" data-name="naam" data-
pk="'.$row_table_1['id'].'" data-url="post.php">Hello World</span>

<span class="editable_textfield" data-type="text" data-name="naam" data-
pk="'.$row_table_1['id'].'" data-url="post.php">Hello World</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for this but for some reason when I use the code above it is not working in my site and I don't get any errors when viewing in console.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where `$(element)` comes from, mabe copy/paste?

You need a selector for the target span. Maybe an extra class that doesn't change with the toggle?

```
<span class="toggletarget textfield" data-type="text" data-name="naam" data-
pk="'.$row_table_1['id'].'" data-url="post.php">'.$row_table_1['naam'].'</span>


$(function() {
    $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
        $(".toggletarget").toggleClass("textfield editable_textfield");
    })
})
```