# jQuery error > inject.preload (newbie)

Tags: jquery, debugging

When running the script as developed in [this StackOverlfow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478620) the script is not responding when I copy the code to my website.

For the first time (from a tip) I have tried F12 and I see a error message, I was hoping to see something like sorry this file is missing since I am a newbie to this kind of debugging.

Can someone explain to me what the problem is and how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable or pause your adblocker if you are using one.

Adblocker has an open ticket on this issue
https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/6744